# How to objectively measure reduction of Time To Market for a diverse portfolio of projects

Tags: metrics, kpi

We, as an RnD department of a small-ish product company, want to focus on reducing Time To Market of the projects that are done in-house.

This raises the question – how do we objectively measure our progress in this regard? The projects that we do vary in scope and risk profile. Since we do hardware as well as software development, the variance might be quite significant – a typical hardware project might take from 8 to 36 months (main constraint being the production time of PCBs and electronic component lead times), while the software projects might take from, say, 3 months to a year or so.

Taking that into consideration, how does one even start measuring "how well we are doing" with regard to reducing overall time to market for our projects? Considering the diversity of the work that we do (and for the most part you could say, that no two projects are the same), how does one come up with a metric or a set of metrics, that would measure that?

Comment: You say that no two projects are the same, but are the components or process steps the same? For example, if you need PCB boards for a project, is that mostly the same way you do it for all projects, or even this is different? Do you have different ways to manage the projects also? Or does that stay the same for projects of the same type?

Comment: Yeah, the process steps are definitely shared between certain projects. Sometimes, to a greater degree, sometimes – to a lesser. If you get right down to individual tasks, there is definitely a closed set of task types.

Comment: Mostly-software projects are managed using iterative planning approach (something akin to agile), mostly-hardware are planned in the waterfall manner.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume these projects are not unique. They may not all be the same, but there should be common components. If you want to improve what you are doing, work on these components. So basically, look at individual steps in your work and see where you can make things better.

You can start by:

- splitting your projects into common themes (e.g. software only projects, hardware only, mix, etc., whatever types you have).
- identify the steps or activities of the processes you use in those themes.
- measure those parts as you have them now.
- see which parts could benefit from some improvements (not all might; keep in mind the Pareto rule that 80% of outcomes comes from 20% of causes). Focus on the big benefits first.
- apply the improvements.
- measure afterwards.

To get started I would recommend a technique called Value Stream Mapping. In very simple terms, every process has:

- steps in which work gets performed, and
- steps of waiting times or handovers between other stages.

You can look at both to try to improve them. Many just look at the work and try to optimize it, automate it, etc., but when they take the time to map out their value streams, they might see that most times are spent in waiting for stuff (waiting for parts to be available, people capacity to be available to take on new work, information to be available, decisions to be made, etc).

See here for details: https://www.techtarget.com/searcherp/definition/value-stream-mapping

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the insights (definitely will look into value stream mapping), but the focus of my question is on _measurement_ of "reducing time to market" for a heterogenous set of projects, as opposed to actual techniques for reducing it.

Comment: Considering the diversity of the projects, to objectively measure them you need to compare apples with apples. If you can’t look at the whole project, you need to look at the parts. With value stream mapping you can group similar projects together by identifying the work performed and the waiting times. And for those you can define metrics specific to the activity. Then, if you do something to improve the activities, you can then use the same metrics to measure again. The sum of those should reflect the reduction of the time to market.